# Extract a portion code from an external page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am creating a personal website for vacation rentals (a joomla website).
The owner has created an ad here: https://www.armor-vacances.com/locat...tml#calendrier
Do you know if there is a way to extract the entire "calendar" portion to display on my website site?
I try some scripts find with "file_get_html" for example but I don't arrive to my goals.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

php can do it, as long as you're not treading on site copyright or robot control issues, and that you can rely on the site you're reading will always have the container you're after, but it's not going to be easy.

It would be good if the site you're scraping has the information in machine ready format using meta tags that it knows programs will be looking for.

Here's a starting point for some scraping code for you (I've cached the page content to a local file so that you don't hit the website too many times each day):

```
<?php
// php7.0

$src  ="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52678213/extract-a-portion-code-from-an-external-page";
$tmpfn="C:/temp/temp.$srcX.$now.html";

$findDivId="Place your ID here";

$now  = date('Y-m-d', time());
$srcX = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/", "", $src);
$srcX = substr($srcX, 0, 155);

if ( file_exists($tmpfn) ) {
    $html=file_get_contents($tmpfn);
}
else {
    $ch = curl_init($src);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);

    $html = curl_exec($ch);
    if ( !$html ) {
        echo curl_error($ch);
        exit;
    }
    curl_close($ch);

    file_put_contents($tmpfn, $html);
}

echo "<LI>html size = ".strlen($html)." bytes";

if ( strcmp($html, "") != 0 ) {
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    @$dom->loadHTML($html);

    $divs = $dom->getElementsByTagName("div"); // or ->getElementsById($id);
    if ( $divs ) {
        echo "<UL>";
        foreach ($divs as $div) {
            echo "<LI>Tag::".$div->nodeName;
            if ( $div->hasAttributes() ) {
                foreach ($div->attributes as $attr) {
                    echo "<BR>Attribute::".$attr->nodeName . "=" . $attr->nodeValue . " ";

                    if ( strcmp($attr->nodeName,'id')==0 
                    and  strcmp($attr->nodeValue,$findDivId)==0 ) {
                        echo "<LI>Found $findDivId!!";
                    }

                }
            }
            echo "<BR>Value::".$div->nodeValue."<BR><BR>";
        }
        echo "</UL>";
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I try your code  and I have the message "html size = 62661 bytes"
The div I want to extract have an id "calendrier", so where I put this name ?

Comment: When I point $src to your https://www.armor-vacances.com/#calendrier page I see
    html size = 127596 bytes
    Tag::div
    Attribute::class=container 
    Value:: Espace Vacancier Ma sélection (0) Espace Propriétaire Déposez une annonce plus de 2000 annonces de location de vacances entre particuliers en Bretagne et Loire Atlantique 
.
.
What version of PHP are you on? I'm on Windows10/PHP7.0

Comment: Thanks. ok the future website will be on php 7.2 (not for the moment, because there is an incompatility with the prod website in php 5.3) 
So I test in an another website on php 7.2 => so it works like you !
But I don't understand where I can specify the id of my div to only extract the div "calendrier" on this page ?

Comment: I've updated the code block above to include a $findDivId variable that you can use to find your specific div

Comment: ok thanks. But I have allways the entire page extracted. Not only the div #calendrier ?